# How to create dictionary of [AudioQuality : NSURL]

Tags: swift, nsurl

In my project i use  [KDEAudioPlayer](https://github.com/delannoyk/AudioPlayer).
Using this lib i try create an AudioItem with lot of audio urls.
This makes the function `AudioItem(soundURLs: [AudioQuality : NSURL])`
But i don't understand how to do array like [AudioQuality : NSURL].
I have an array with audio urls, that look like [NSURL].
How can i do an array  [AudioQuality : NSURL] from my array [NSURL]

AudioItem with one url i can create like this:

```
let item = AudioItem(highQualitySoundURL: trackUrls[0])
```

How can i create AudioItem with lot of audio Urls and sound quality, that look like `[AudioQuality : NSURL]`?

Answer (score 2):

`[AudioQuality : NSURL]` is not an `Array` it is a `NSDictionary` consist of `AudioQuality` and `NSURL` type

so basically it is

```
let dict:NSDictionary = [AudioQuality:NSURL]() as NSDictionary

let NSUrlArray = [nsurl1,nsurl2]
let AudioQualityArray = [audio1,audio2]


for (index, value) in NSUrlArray.enumerate(){
  dict.setValue(value,AudioQualityArray[index])
}

print(dict) // this is what you want
```

Comment: So, how to transform [NSURL] to [AudioQuality:NSUrl]?

Comment: I got an error 'Value of type [AudioQuality:NSURL] has no member 'setValue'

Comment: can you check again?